# Двоеточие или тире после "ФСБ"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография

> Дело возбуждено в отношении тайного агента ФСБ(:) главы управы одного из районов города(,) лейтенанта милиции в отставке(,) Альберта Антонова.

Двоеточие или тире? А также другие знаки препинания! И ещё "главы управы" с каких букв (строчных или заглавных)?

Comment: "И ещё "главы управы" с каких букв (строчных или заглавных)?" А в этом предложении не надо что-нибудь поставить после "ещё" и перед "с каких букв" ? А если скобки убрать, то какой знак перед "строчных" поставить?

Comment: Насчёт "главы управы" — см. ответ: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286092

Answer (score 1):

- Вариант 1.

**Дело возбуждено в отношении тайного агента ФСБ главы управы одного из районов города лейтенанта милиции в отставке Альберта Антонова.**

Пояснение: "Альберта Антонова" — это *определяемое слово* (в данном случае два слова), а всё, что перед ним, — это *неоднородные распространённые приложения* (см. Розенталь "Пунктуация", § 11.2).

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Около 20.00 я попросил дежурного... отпустить меня на ужин и попросил
> находившегося в это время в отделении милиции *старшего инспектора УР
> старшего лейтенанта милиции Мишина  В.  Н.* (курсив мой — N.) подменить меня до 22.00.

- Вариант 2.

**Дело возбуждено в отношении тайного агента ФСБ — главы управы одного из районов города лейтенанта милиции в отставке Альберта Антонова.**

Пояснение: здесь "Альберта Антонова" и весь стоящий перед ним состав приложений рассматривается как *присоединительная конструкция*, а тире заменяет выражение "то есть" (см. Розенталь "Пунктуация", § 23):

> При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным
> членом предложения часто ставится тире: <...> *Профессия его была самая мирная — учитель*; *На выполнение
> работы потребовалось меньше, чем мы ожидали, — два месяца*; *То ли он
> решил, что ошибся — честного человека не распознал, то ли по другой
> причине, но он охотно выполнил просьбу.*

Comment: Советую говорить в таких случаях, как лучше и почему, тогда ответы будут ещё лучше.

Comment: @oleedd учту, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы, честно говоря, запятые не поставила, так как здесь об одном человеке же говорится, а если поставить запятые, то четыре человека получится. Четыре человека под уголовным делом вместо одного. И всё из-за неправильной пунктуации!

Вы такие вопросы формулируйте по-другому, так как люди могут бояться, что их вызовут на Лубянку, если они ответят. Вы историю читали, Агент Сисин?

Comment: Nektoid, у меня нет репутации (баллов не хватает), чтобы я могла Вас комментировать, поэтому напишу здесь! Прекрасный ответ, спасибо!